# semanage command having python issue

Tags: almalinux

I'm trying to make selinux permissive for one of the process (drbd) in Almalinux 8.8 and I'm facing the below python issue while using semanage command,

```
`   [root@dnd-st-6-0-0-28-lt-ha1 admin]# semanage permissive -a drbd_t
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/sbin/semanage", line 1000, in <module>
        do_parser()
      File "/sbin/semanage", line 970, in do_parser
        commandParser = createCommandParser()
      File "/sbin/semanage", line 900, in createCommandParser
        import seobject
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seobject.py", line 33, in <module>
        import sepolicy
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sepolicy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        import setools
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setools/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution("setools").version
    AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'get_distribution'
`
```

Does anyone have any idea?

```
`   [admin@dnd-st-6-0-0-28-lt-ha1 ~]$ cat /etc/release
    AlmaLinux release 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)
    Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Source)
    AlmaLinux release 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)
    NAME="AlmaLinux"
    VERSION="8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)"
    ID="almalinux"
    ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora"
    VERSION_ID="8.8"
    PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
    PRETTY_NAME="AlmaLinux 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)"
    ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
    LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
    CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos"
    HOME_URL="https://almalinux.org/"
    DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.almalinux.org/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.almalinux.org/"

    ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT="AlmaLinux-8"
    ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8.8"
    REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="AlmaLinux"
    REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.8"
    AlmaLinux release 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)
    AlmaLinux release 8.8 (Sapphire Caracal)
    cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos
`
```

Regards,
Srini